# Is there a Linq method that does .SelectMany(x => x)?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to flatten an enumerable of enumerables of the same type. In FP it would be a standard function `concat` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353462.aspx). What do I do in C# (Linq)?

Comment: what is wrong with SelectMany ? it is a LINQ method as well.

Comment: I think you want an answer to a question that you couldn't asked

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is there a LinQ method that does `.SelectMany(x => x)`? Yes, there is. It's `.SelectMany(x => x)`. Did I miss the joke?

Comment: to all of you who doesn't understand, consider a question: (Me) Is there anyone in your forest who can cut a tree with a knife (?) swinging up and down? From where I am we call such person an axeman and he uses his ax for doing that. ... (You) What is wrong with anybody who can hold a knife and swing it up and down? I don't understand it. Yes of course there is. It can be any person who can hold an knife and swing it up and down. Even you can do it if you hold your knife and cut a tree with it by swinging it up and down. Is this question a joke? Yes, it must be a joke.

Comment: The tree-knife analogy is making my head hurt. What does it mean???

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you mean "without having to specify the `x => x`": no - but you could just *write one*:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source) {
    return source.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

edit: but perhaps a parameterless-`SelectMany` is a clearer name, for consistency:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source) {
    return source.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "no". There is a linq method that does `SelectMany`. It's `SelectMany`!

Comment: @DavidS. the question is not "is there a method that does `SelectMany`?"; it is more specific: "is there a method that does `SelectMany(x => x)`?". And the answer to *that* is: no.

Comment: Maybe I'm just slow today, but you *just used it*: `source.SelectMany(x => x);`

Comment: @DavidS. it seems entirely obvious to me that the question means "without having to specify the `x => x`". Now, I would be entirely willing to grant that the method shown above would perhaps be better named as a parameterless-`SelectMany`, but the intent of not specifying the selector seems entirely clear.

Comment: @MarcGravell, you entirely right with your last comment, as for `Concat` it's already taken

Comment: @AlekseyBykov Call it `Flatten` then?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov fortunately, not by a single-parameter overload - but yeah, worth avoiding name confusion

Comment: I agree that a parameterless `SelectMany` is clearer.  It's relatively consistent with Linq's existing strategy (e.g. for `Any` and `First`).  I think it is unlikely that Microsoft will introduce an implementation for parameterless `SelectMany` that isn't a drop-in replacement for this extension method, so this probably won't cause naming collisions for future Framework extension methods, except in the case of semantically identically collisions (which are trivially resolved by deleting the custom `SelectMany`).

Answer (score -2):

`IEnumerable.SelectMany(x => x.ToList())` should do this for you.

Comment: Wonder someone clicked the downvote literally 1 second after I submitted the answer. :)

Comment: that `x => x.ToList()` is entirely unnecessary and actively expensive; it was better with `x => x`